# python newbie - how to import library

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I installed the 'pandas' module and now I need to run it at my command line, but it is not available. How to make it available?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named 'pandas'

In [2]:
```

Comment: You imported fine. `pandas` doesn't come with Python. How did you install it?

Comment: I already installed it by "pip install pandas" without problem.

Comment: One of the first questions is: how did you install pandas? If `import pandas ...` raises an `ImportError`, the module simply cannot be found in the current directory or in site-packages or in $PYTHON_PATH.

Comment: If you installed it via `pip install pandas`, it was probably the wrong pip. You probably have several python versions installed...

Comment: yes. I re-installed and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module can't be found in the current directory, in pythons site-packages folder or in any path defined in the `$PYTHON_PATH` environment variable.

If you installed pandas via `pip install pandas` and encounter an `ImportError`, you most likely have a problem due to multiple python distributions installed on your system.

Look carefully at the output of `pip install pandas` and examine the folders in its output. Find out which executable you are running when calling python via `which python` and look at the version numbers.

This is a very common problem btw. so prepare for a close of this question.